# Python запись в csv в первой колонке 1 строка во второй колонке несколько строк

Tags: python, csv, запись

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на python с помощью модуля csv можно организовать такой формат записи, где на каждой итерации в первую колонку будет записываться 1 строка, а во вторую несколько строк из списка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто внести пустое значение в первую колонку. Пример:

```
import csv

data = {"раздел1": ["запись1", "запись2", "запись3"]}
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for k, v in data.items():
        spamwriter.writerow((k,v[0]))
        if len(v)>1:
            for entry in v[1:]:
                spamwriter.writerow(("",entry))
```

[image: Пример]